# Как сделать отлавливатель команд в telegram?

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужно что бы человек написал боту(в телеграмме) сообщение $gen, и скрипт сгенерировал ему пароль и отправил, как сделать?

```
import telebot
import config
import os
import mcrcon
import string
from random import choice

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный для создания пароля".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не знаю команды либо вопроса, используй $gen".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html')

def random_password():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    while True:
        password = ''.join(choice(alphabet) for i in range(8))
        if (any(symbol.islower() for symbol in password)
                and any(symbol.isupper() for symbol in password)
                and sum(symbol.isdigit() for symbol in password) >= 1):
            return password

@bot.message_handler(commands=['gen'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(random_password()))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: У вас не получается генерация пароля или вообще всё?

Comment: нужно написать скрипт, который при получении сообщения $gen будет генерировать пароль и отсылать его человеку ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Можно пример скрипта Эникейщик?

Comment: @xIgorx можно сначала пример вашего скрипта, и что у вас в нём не работает?

Comment: Делаете *$gen* командой для бота, пишите логику генерации пароля и отправляете его. Изи

Comment: дайте пример скрипта пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string
from random import choice

def random_password():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    while True:
        password = ''.join(choice(alphabet) for i in range(8))
        if (any(symbol.islower() for symbol in password)
                and any(symbol.isupper() for symbol in password)
                and sum(symbol.isdigit() for symbol in password) >= 1):
            return password


@bot.message_handler(commands=['gen'])
def some(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(random_password()))
```

Comment: не работает, давай я попробую скинуть весь код что бы ты посмотрел?

Comment: я проверил код из ответа прежде чем публиковать. скидывайте..

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста что там не так

Comment: расположите блок @bot.message_handler(commands=['gen']) перед @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: если ответ оказался полезным, и решает ваш вопрос, пожалуйста пометьте его как решение. спасибо

Comment: а как, подскажи ещё пожалуйста?

Comment: около ответа есть кнопка в виде галочки